# Connect Azure SQL Database (PAAS) to SQL Assesment

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have an existing Azure SQL DB (Paas solution) in resource group 1. I created a new OMS work space in Log Analytics resource group 2. I want to connect SQL DB in resource group 1 to OMS work space for SQL assessment in resource group 2.

How can enable the connectivity ?

I followed the article from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-sql-assessment

If I understand it correctly , I don't need to install any agent. How can I add SQL DB to SQL Assessment .

Currently I see no DB connected in SQL assessment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, SQL Assessment solution is designed for on premise SQL Server or SQL Database (IaaS). For Azure SQL Database(PaaS), you should use [the Azure SQL Analytics solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-azure-sql) instead of SQL Assessment.

> The Azure SQL Analytics solution doesn't use agents to connect to the Log Analytics service.